# Problem upgrading Craft CMS?

Tags: error-message

When trying to upgrade Craft CMS automatically we get a message relative to the SSL certificate of the CDN being incorrect, though it works fine on a local machine.

> Craft was unable to install this update :(
>
> [curl] 51: SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target
>   host name 'download.craftcdn.com' [url]
>   https://download.craftcdn.com/craft/2.6/2.6.2967/Patch/2.6.2962/41d682834df8c739ead7a1abab6a4571.zip

Anybody else getting this?

Answer (score 1):

That `cURL 51` error usually means that your server doesn't understand the [SNI SSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) certificate we have installed at https://craftcms.com and https://craftcdn.com.

Technically there are 3 things a server needs to recognize SNI SSL certs:

1. Using a version of cURL that supports it, at least 7.18.1 (8 years old: https://curl.haxx.se/changes.html)
2. Using a version of cURL compiled against a library that supports SNI, e.g. OpenSSL 0.9.8j (depending on the compilation options some older versions. 7 years old: https://www.openssl.org/news/changelog.html)
3. Using TLS 1.0 at least (not SSLv3)

Once the box Craft is on meets those requirements, it should start working.